# How to delete a tag that shows up only on inspect element on my website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, tradingview-api

I have embedded a widget on my website which has a watermark which can't be removed (can't even pay to remove it)

Here's the code i have embedded:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
 {
  "symbols": [
{
  "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
  "title": "Bitcoin"
},
{
  "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
  "title": "Ethereum"
},
{
  "description": "APE",
  "proName": "BINANCE:APEUSDT"
},
{
  "description": "Solana",
  "proName": "BINANCE:SOLUSDT"
},
{
  "description": "DOGE",
  "proName": "BINANCE:DOGEUSDT"
},
{
  "description": "MATIC",
  "proName": "BINANCE:MATICUSDT"
}
 ],
"showSymbolLogo": true,
"colorTheme": "light",
"isTransparent": true,
"displayMode": "regular",
"locale": "en"  }
  </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Here's a screenshot of a watermark:
https://prnt.sc/t5SjXZ8icjTH

The tag containing the watermark looks like this:

<a href="https://www.tradingview.com/?utm_campaign=ticker-tape&utm_medium=widget&utm_source=localhost" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="label-dkyS18j2 label-cJj3kEO9 end-dkyS18j2 top-dkyS18j2 js-copyright-label"

This code shows up only on the inspect element, not in the embedded script.

Whenever i delete the class="label-dkyS18j2 label-cJj3kEO9 end-dkyS18j2 top-dkyS18j2 js-copyright-label" through inspect element, the watermark is gone, and everything works live.

How do i remove that on my website from the code?

I have tried putting this in my webpage code, but it doesn't work

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.label-dkyS18j2 label-cJj3kEO9 end-dkyS18j2 top-dkyS18j2 js-copyright-label').hide()
    });
    </script>
```

This is driving me nuts, hope someone can assist

Comment: class="label-dkyS18j2 label-cJj3kEO9 end-dkyS18j2 top-dkyS18j2 js-copyright-label" is static so removing it will solve the issue

Answer (score -3):

**"I have embedded a widget on my website which has a watermark which can't be removed (can't even pay to remove it)"**

Do you realize that maybe, just maybe.. it has a reason you can't remove the watermark/copyright/trademark ? And that the people who gave you a free widget, only want some exposure in return. I'm even doubting if this question doesn't go against the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: The company who gave this free widget are already huge, and are not going to get any exposure from my school project. The watermark just looks ugly on the phone.

Also, whenever someone clicks on any crypto price they are redirected to that website, which is fine. It's just the watermark which is annoying and looks rly bad on phone

Comment: Not even relevant, it's a unethical move. ‍♂️